# Display content only if URL contains specific parameter

Tags: url, parameters

I would like to display content only if the url contains certain parameter. In the case is checked whether the URL exists, for example, the parameter ?offset=10. If the parameter exists (site.com/post-name?offset=10) is shown the content X, otherwise the content is shown Y.

Eg:

```
function parameterUrl() {
$str = "?offset=10";
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
if ($uri == "http://site.com/post-name$str") {
echo "Show this";
}
 else {
}
}
```

But the above function is not working. Can anyone help. Any idea is welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameters are stored in the `$_GET` globals array.

You need:

```
if (isset($_GET['offset']) && $_GET['offset'] == 10)
{
echo "show this";
}
else {
echo "show that";
}
```

**Update from Comment**

If you are going to have multiple quantities then a switch statement would be better:

```
if (isset($_GET['offset']))
{
    switch($_GET['offset'])
    {
        case 10:
            echo "show for 10";
        break;

        case 20:
            echo "show for 20";
        break;

        case 30:
            echo "show for 30;
        break;
//and so on
    }
}
else {
echo "show for no offset";
}
```

Comment: Ok @Liam Bailey, at first worked perfectly. Actually the parameters are added in amounts of 10 (offset=10, offset=20, ... 30, ...). So for other parameters url, I'm using "elseif": `if (isset($_GET['offset']) && $_GET['offset'] == 10) { echo "show this"; } elseif (isset($_GET['offset']) && $_GET['offset'] == 20) {
echo "show this"; }`

Comment: Great, I did not remember how to use "switch", thus facilitates a bit, thanks for the support, even more.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the appropriate key in the `$_GET` associative array is set.

```
isset($_GET['offset'])
```

Thus, in your code, it will be:

```
<?php 
function parameterUrl() {
  if (isset($_GET['offset'])) {
    echo "Show this";
  }
  else {
  }
} 
?>
```

Optionally if it needs to be equal to 10, use `(isset($_GET['offset']) && $_GET['offset'] == 10)`.

Comment: Thank @ronalchn, its tip, and the tip of Liam Bailey, came in handy.